# Is it possible to bridge an IP created by a 4G modem merged with WWAN0 network with a virtual static IP?

Tags: raspbian, static-ip

Good afternoon,

I have a Telit modem that was configured to generate an IP from an ISP to merge it with a WWAN0 network in the Raspberry Pi. However, it is working perfectly, but disadvantage of it is that every time the board restarts, the modem connects to a different IP, which shall be unknown.

My question is, is it possible by any mean to merge/bridge the IP created by WWAN0 to a virtual static IP?

Thanks in advance.